# Trigger before insertion

Tags: mysql

Hi I need to write a trigger to check if the value is existing in a column, if yes then do not insert it and through and error. 
There is a column which can have only two values(same as bool) DEFAULT or NONDEFAULT.

This column can have multiple NONDEFAULT value but only one DEFAULT value in column.

If the DEFAULT exists in table, we need to through an error and shall not insert the new row.

Kindly help

```
create trigger status_value before insert on TABLE for each row
begin 
if new.status=DEFAULT AND select count(status) from TABLE where status=DEFAULT)
then 
signal sqlstate = '4500' 
set message_text = 'can not update, default value already present'
end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger status_value before insert on TABLE for each row
begin 
if (new.status='DEFAULT' AND EXISTS (select 1 from TABLE where status='DEFAULT'))
then 
signal sqlstate = '4500'
set message_text = 'can not update, default value already present';
end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

I'm assuming, that you mean the value of the column is a string "default", not the default value you defined when creating the table.